# Mock a statement by using MockIto

Tags: junit, mockito, junit4

I want to write a test method for a service method. In this service method we are calling a query that fetch the data from database and that value is used in the function to do some processing. I want to stub only this db call. here is my function

```
public arraylist retrieveSomthing(JdbcTemplate){

//some processing is happening

List<Map<String,Object>> result = JdbcTemplate.queryForList("QueryName");

//some processing is happening for the result return from the query.


}
```

I want to write the test for the above function but I want to stub only the Jdbc.queryforList  statement.

Please help me How to go stub the statement.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking static methods with Mockito](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito)

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Test
 public void testRetrieveSomthing() {
  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
  List < .. > results = ///something you would do dummy return
  when(jdbcTemplate.queryForList(anyString())).thenReturn(results);
  List < .. > alist = instance.retrieveSomthing(jdbcTemplate);
  assertEquals(alist, expectedList);

 }
```

Comment: Again I tried with matchers like anyString() and anyCollections() but still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do

1) Mock the jdbctemplate object like below:

```
@Mock private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

2) Since jdbcTemplate.queryForList("QueryName") returns list, make sure that you have created a List object and returning that value while stubbing (like below)

```
    List<Example> result = new ArrayList();
     result.add("dummy values");
     result.add("dummy values");
```

then

```
    //import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
    Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.queryForList(anyString()).thenReturn(result);
```

PS: Points to remember while mocking and stubbing are,

1) while dealing with List objects create new object and return as on-stubbing value of actual test class

2) Use matchers like anyString() instead of using some text.

Hope it is useful.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I did exactly what you mentioned but always I am getting null as result. here is my test function

Comment: public void retrieveRestrictedUpcsTestEquals(){
ArrayList<String> upcsList=new ArrayList<String>();
upcsList.add(TestDataConstants.UPC1);
List<Map<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>()
Map<String,Object> upc_nbr=new HashMap<String,Object>();
upc_nbr.put("upc_nbr", 2)
result.add(upc_nbr); Mockito.when(wmJdbcTemplate.queryForList(FETCH_RSTRCTED_UPC_QRY,upcsList)).thenReturn(result);
ArrayList<String> upcList =daoImpl.retrieveRestrictedUpcs(wmJdbcTemplate);
  assertTrue(upcList.size()==2);

Comment: I tried with the matchers as well but getting the same result. not sure If I am doing anything wrong. Please help.

Comment: @Test
 public void retrieveRestrictedUpcsTestEquals(){
    
  List<Map<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
  Map<String,Object> upc_nbr=new HashMap<String,Object>();
  upc_nbr.put("upc_nbr", 2);
  result.add(upc_nbr);
  upc_nbr=new HashMap<String,Object>();
  upc_nbr.put("upc_nbr", 3);
  result.add(upc_nbr);
  
  Mockito.when(wmJdbcTemplate.queryForList(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyCollection())).thenReturn(result);
  ArrayList<String> upcList = daoImpl.retrieveRestrictedUpcs(wmJdbcTemplate);
  assertTrue(upcList.size()==2);
 }

Comment: Are you getting null as result or NullPointerException, if it's exception could you paste here that would be easy to help you.

Comment: Exceptions -> java.lang.AssertionError
 at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
 at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
 at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)
 at com.walmart.ecommerce.restriction.dao.impl.test.RestrictDaoImplTest.retrieveRestrictedUpcsTestEquals(RestrictDaoImplTest.java:102)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)atsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

Comment: Yes I am not getting the desired result that I am trying to mock